# Proof of expression for Christoffel symbols of the first kind, $[i , j k] = {\bf e}_i \cdot \frac{\partial {\bf e}_j}{\partial x^k}$

Tags: vector-analysis, tensors

On page 155 of [Vector and Tensor Analysis with Applications](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=CRIjIx2ac6AC), by A.I Borishenko and I.E. Tarapov, the authors assert that,

$$\frac{\partial {\bf e}_j}{\partial x^k} = \left\{  i \atop j \; k \right\} {\bf e}_i$$
and
$$ [i,jk] = \frac{\partial {\bf e}_j}{\partial x_k} {\bf e}^i $$
imply that
$$[i , j k] = {\bf e}_i \cdot \frac{\partial {\bf e}_j}{\partial x^k}$$

Unfortunately, I am unable to show how the final equation follows from the first two.

**Update**

Extract from the text

[image]

---

[image]
[image]

The derivative of ${\bf e}_j$ is first covariant, then contravariant, then covariant. Besides surely $\left\{  i \atop j \; k \right\}$ cannot be expansion coefficients of $\frac{\partial {\bf e}_j}{\partial x_k}$. Could this be a typo?

Comment: I can't answer the question but I've usually seen the Christoffel symbol of the first kind defined as $[i,jk]=g_{il}\left\{l \atop j\; k\right\}$ where $g_{il}=\mathbf e_i\cdot\mathbf e_l$ is the metric tensor after which the result follows fairly simply. I don't follow the second and third equations, it looks like the co-/contravariant (roof/cellar) components don't agree.

Comment: The text follows with the relationship between both the Christoffel's symbols of the first and second kind, that you wrote, without explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer to this question has been posted on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371961/christoffel-symbols-as-the-expansion-coefficients-of-covariant-contravariant-der/372046#372046).

---

*I have added this extra content to stop the system from converting my answer to a comment.*